# Laravel 6.3 The site can't reached

Tags: php, server, forge, laravel-6

I have a project build in Laravel 6.3, when I use it in localhost it works fine but when I put all the code to the server by using forge, I am seeing a problem please check out this video to understand it better.

Video Link: https://www.loom.com/share/51d691b1fa1847548f8b334c28e13ae1

Thanks

Comment: Check your server (php) logs and put it here if it's possible. I did faced with the same problem before when php throws an exception and doesn't catches anywhere (usually happens when display_errors were disabled).

Comment: Does the project `/storage/log` of laravel itself, contain any log files? Maybe you can find in the log files what the stacktrace and exception is?

Comment: I tried to ssh and look into log folder but there was no laravel.log file